# Use of undeclared type "ParallaxHeaderView"

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I added the ParallaxHeaderView folder but I'm getting an error saying that it undeclared.

```
import UIKit

class TimelineViewController:  UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

let cellData = CellData()

let tableViewCellIdentifier = "tableCell"
let bottomCellIdentifier = "bottomTableCell"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let headerImage = UIImage(named: "Shreyas.png")
```

Getting  error  on  this  line

```
    let headerView: ParallaxHeaderView = ParallaxHeaderView.parallaxHeaderViewWithImage(headerImage, forSize: CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 200.0)) as! ParallaxHeaderView

    // Tap Gesture to return to previous view
    headerView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "headerTapped")
    headerView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

    // Label settings
    headerView.headerTitleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Medium", size: CGFloat(32.0))
    headerView.headerTitleLabel.text = "Shreyas Papinwar"
    headerView.headerTitleLabel.frame.origin.y -= 60.0

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
}

override func preferredStatusBarStyle() -> UIStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    if segue.identifier == "facebook.Segue" {
        let webVC: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
        webVC.webURL = "https://facebook.com/the3seconds"
    }

    else if segue.identifier == "twitterSegue" {
        let webVC: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
        webVC.webURL = "https://twitter.com/spapinwar"
    }

    else if segue.identifier == "docSegue" {
        let webVC: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
        webVC.webURL = "http://github.com"
    }

    else if segue.identifier == "sheetSegue" {
        let webVC: WebViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! WebViewController
        webVC.webURL = "http://google.com"
    }

    else {
        print("Unexpected segue identifier: \(segue.identifier)")
    }

}

// MARK: - UITableViewDataSource methods

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if section == 0 {
        return cellData.cells.count
    }
    else {
        return 1
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(tableViewCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TimelineTableViewCell

        let entry = cellData.cells[indexPath.row]

        let cellDate = entry.date
        let cellLineImage = UIImage(named: entry.line)

        cell.tableCellDate.text = cellDate
        cell.tableCellLineImage.image = cellLineImage
        cell.tableCellLabel.text = entry.labelText

        return cell
    }
    else {
        let bottomCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(bottomCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BottomTableViewCell

        return bottomCell
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableView methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        return CGFloat(160.0)
    }
    else {
        return CGFloat(300.0)
    }
}

// MARK: - UITableViewDelegate methods

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    let row = indexPath.row

    print(cellData.cells[row].labelText)
}

// MARK: UIScrollViewDelegate methods

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let header: ParallaxHeaderView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView as! ParallaxHeaderView
    header.layoutHeaderViewForScrollViewOffset(scrollView.contentOffset)

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = header
}

// MARK: - Helper methods

func headerTapped() {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

}

Comment: A few things would help: 1) You're saying you get an error on "this" line, but then include over 100 lines of code.  Which line is the problem? Do the rest of the lines you share have direct significance? If so, please summarize what that significance is.  2) Please share the exact error.  If the output gives any other context, share that too.

Comment: When you say you added a "folder", can you be more specific?  What files were involved and did you make them part of your target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add a `headerViews` to your `tableView`? You'll need couple of `UITableViewDelegate` methods.

`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:` 
 `tableView:heightForHeaderInSection`

And you can use XIB files for creating custom `headerView`. XIB files allows you more than default.